# how can i use 'headed by'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I am reading a news paper now. I tried to figure out the meaning, but I could not.

The sentence in question is taken from [The New Indian Express](http://www.newindianexpress.com/nation/2018/may/07/kathua-rape-and-murder-case-supreme-court-transfers-trial-to-pathankot-rules-out-cbi-probe-1811402.html):

> *However, a bench headed by Chief Justice Dipak Misra accepted the plea by the victim's father* [...]

In the sentence I want to know the meaning of **'headed by'**. Is it a noun, a verb or an adjective? Please also tell me the meaning of headed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headed is a verb past participle (the verb is 'head') acting as an adjective meaning "led or controlled". The bench of judges was led or controlled by Chief Justice Misra.

> 2 head or head up [TRANSITIVE] to be in control of a group or an
>   organization Lord Justice Scott will head the inquiry. You will work
>   with the management team headed by Miles Broughton.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/head_2#head_2__6